# Int and Num type of haskell

Tags: function, variables, haskell, types

I have below code to take the args to set some offset time.

```
setOffsetTime :: (Ord a, Num b)=>[a] -> b
setOffsetTime [] = 200
setOffsetTime (x:xs) = read x::Int
```

But compiler says "**Could not deduce (b ~ Int) from the context (Ord a, Num b) bound by the type signature for setOffsetTime :: (Ord a, Num b) => [a] -> b**

Also I found I could not use 200.0 if I want float as the default value. The compilers says  "Could not deduce (Fractional b) arising from the literal `200.0'"

Could any one show me some code as a function (not in the prelude) that takes an arg to store some variable so I can use in other function? I can do this in the main = do, but hope 
to use an elegant function to achieve this.
Is there any global constant stuff in Hasekll? I googled it, but seems not.

I wanna use Haskell to replace some of my python script although it is not easy.

Comment: Just a remark: in the second equation of `setOffsetTime` you explicitly state that the result of `read x` should be an `Int`. This immediately implies that the result type of your function is `Int` and not the more general `b` for `Num b`. And that is exactly what the compiler tells you (in his own words).

Comment: Furthermore the type of `read` is `Read a => String -> a`, hence its argument (`x` in your case) must be of type `String`, but you are using `a` for `Ord a`.

Comment: Also I do not quite understand what your goal is. Could you try to explain it more concretely and give an example?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, chris. I want a function which can take a string list, then convert the first element to Float, at last output the Float. If the list is empty, output 200.0 @chris

Comment: Well, than you basically already have all you want in your `setOffsetTime` and just have to correct some types. E.g., drop the `Ord a` contraint and replace `[a]` with `[String]`. Further drop `Num b` and replace `b` by `Float`. And also drop `... :: Int` from the last line.

Comment: It works very well now. This type class stuff bothered me almost the whole morning. Gonna read more Haskell tutorials later. Thank you @chris

Answer (score 6):

I think this type signature doesn't quite mean what you think it does:

`setOffsetTime :: (Ord a, Num b)=>[a] -> b`

What that says is "if you give me a value of type `[a]`, for any type `a` **you** choose that is a member of the `Ord` type class, I will give you a value of type `b`, for any type `b` that **you** choose that is a member of the `Num` type class". The *caller* gets to pick the particular types `a` and `b` that are used each time `setOffsetTime` is called.

So trying to return a value of type `Int` (or `Float`, or any particular type) doesn't make sense. `Int` is indeed a member of the type class `Num`, but it's not *any* member of the type class `Num`. According to that type signature, I should be able to make a brand new instance of `Num` that you've never seen before, import `setOffsetTime` from your module, and call it to get a value of my new type.

To come up with an acceptable return value, you can *only* use functions that likewise return an arbitrary `Num`. You can't use any functions of particular concrete types.

Existential types are essentially a mechanism for allowing the callee to choose the value for a type variable (and then the caller has to be written to work regardless of what that type is), but that's not really something you want to be getting into while you're still learning.

Answer (score 4):

If you are convinced that the implementation of your function is correct, i.e., that it should interpret the first element in its input list as the number to return and return `200` if there is no such argument, then you only need to make sure that the type signature matches that implementation (which it does not do, right now).

To do so, you could, for example, remove the type signature and ask ghci to infer the type:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let setOffsetTime []       = 200
Prelude|     setOffsetTime (x : xs) = read x :: Int
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t setOffsetTime
setOffsetTime :: [String] -> Int
Prelude> :q
Leaving GHCi.

$
```

And indeed,

```
setOffsetTime          :: [String] -> Int
setOffsetTime []       =  200
setOffsetTime (x : xs) =  read x :: Int
```

compiles fine.

If you want a slightly more general type, you can drop the ascription `:: Int` from the second case. The above method then tells you that you can write

```
setOffsetTime          :: (Num a, Read a) => [String] -> a
setOffsetTime []       =  200
setOffsetTime (x : xs) =  read x
```

---

From the comment that you added to your question, I understand that you want your function to return a floating-point number. In that case, you can write

```
setOffsetTime          :: [String] -> Float
setOffsetTime []       =  200.0
setOffsetTime (x : xs) =  read x
```

or, more general:

```
setOffsetTime          :: (Fractional a, Read a) => [String] -> a
setOffsetTime []       =  200.0
setOffsetTime (x : xs) =  read x
```

Comment: There's no need to use `200.0` for the float versions, using `200` works just fine.

Comment: Absolutely. (But I did want the function to match the last snippet.)

Comment: And the last snippet can also use `200`.